# Installation failed while running the app, getting Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

Tags: android

I have updated the android studio to 'Android studio 2.0 Preview 4'. Created an Sample app while start executing the project, i am getting the below content in alert box

[image]

Even, if i click "OK". i am getting the error as

DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.example.evuser.demoproject
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Kindly guide me with possible suggestions. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use SDK tools from Preview channel (see in SDK Manager), try to install stable version of SDK tools